# Webform Integration Error: cannot redeclare _webform_components_form_rows()

Tags: drupal, webform-civicrm

I have recently enabled Drupal CiviCRM Webform Integration and it's working, however, when I view the webform components (Webform > From components) for a form that I have enabled CiviCRM processing, I get the following error. I can view other webform settings. If nothing else, I'm just trying either eliminate other webform elements and change the section name from "contact 1".

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare _webform_components_form_rows()
>   (previously declared in
>   /var/www/html/example/docroot/sites/all/modules/contrib/webform/includes/webform.components.inc:223)
>   in
>   /var/www/html/example/docroot/sites/all/modules/contrib/webform_civicrm/webform_civicrm_admin.inc
>   on line 1506

I am using Drupal 7.50 with CiviCRM 4.7.15 and Webform 7.x-4.14, CiviCRM Webform 7.x-3.5

Comment: What versions of CiviCRM, Webform, and Webform-CiviCRM are you using?

Comment: Oops, I forgot to add that and you solved my problem just by mentioning it. Want to post the answer?

Comment: No it's fine -- just don't forget to come back and mark the answer below as accepted when it allows you to. :) Glad it's solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't upgrade webform_civicrm, the Webform CiviCRM integration module to the latest and compatible version. Once I updated the module, the problem went away.

https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm

[image]